# ggplot python handling time data over many weeks at hourly resolution

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I am plotting journey time for a series of roads at hourly resolution, with data over a few weeks.

I can plot using unix time, but that isn't very intuitive. This is 7 days worth of data.

[image]

I used a function to manipulate the `time` field in order to give the date and hour:

```
def plot_time(time):
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H')
```

However, this results in ggplot throwing a value error when trying to plot:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2016-04-13-00
```

Is there a simpler means of displaying date and some hour?

Alternatively I could plot unix time with a date scale on the axis but it would be nice to have some hour resolution on the axis.

Comment: With `ggplot2`, an easy format to use is `POSIXct`. Could you provide us the original format of the time variable ?

Comment: The original format is Unix epoch time. For example `1456732801`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`POSIXct` was the key here as bVa said.

```
ggplot(aes(x=as.POSIXct(epoch_time,origin="1970-01-01"),y=lambda)
```

Once the epoch time was formated POSIXct, it was possible to use `scale_x_datetime()`

I settled on:

```
+ scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("1 day"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [scale_date](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html) is what you exactly need.

Comment: It was useful post formatting the time as POSIXct. Thanks!